# How to make a paragraph inside \resumeSubHeadingListStart?

Tags: paragraphs

I have this code here

```
\section{Short personal description}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
First paragraph here. \par                          
Other paragraph start
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

I aspect to obtain something similar to this the classical paragraphing in LaTeX

```
First paragraph
   Second paragraph
```

Comment: Where is `\resumeSubHeadingListStart` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually works.

\par First paragraph here. \\ ( '\\' to end line and enter on new line or use '\newline')

\par Other paragraph here \\

To manual indent the paragraph you can use \hspace{10pt} before \par

For Paragraphing and Sub-paragraphing with heading you can use below commands.

**Example :**

\paragraph{Paragraph}
Some more text.
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
Even more text.

**Output:**

**Paragraph** Some more text.
  **Subparagraph** Even more text.